# Arcade Expression to Intersect Features and add Attribute to Popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, arcade

New to Arcade. I have two features in an AGOL map, "SS Parcels" and "SS Zoning". I would like to configure the popup for "SS Parcels" to also display the zoning code from "SS Zoning".

It seems like this is possible from this article:
[Overlapping Features in Pop-Ups](https://community.esri.com/community/gis/web-gis/arcgisonline/blog/2018/12/10/overlapping-features-in-pop-ups-quick-introduction-to-using-featuresets-with-arcade)

However I can't seem to make my code work at all. It looks like the function "Intersects" actually returns a Boolean, maybe this was changed since the article was written. If I instead use the function "Intersection", which returns a geometry, my code looks like this:

```
var intersectLayer = Intersection(Buffer($feature, -10, 'feet'),FeatureSetByName($map, 'SS Zoning'))
for (var f in intersectLayer){
return f.ZONING
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had some mismatched Layer names between the actual Layer name in the Item Description and the item in the Map Legend. I renamed everything to match and this solved my problem. Here is the final code which also adds some functionality to list multiple Zones if a parcel crosses a boundary.

```
var intersectLayer = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map, "South Strabane 
Zoning"),Buffer($feature, -10, 'feet'))
var zones = ""
for (var f in intersectLayer){
    zones = concatenate(zones,f.ZONING," ")
}
return zones
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do the following:

```
var intersectLayer = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map, 'SS Zoning'), $feature),Buffer($feature, -10, 'feet');
for (var f in intersectLayer){
    return f.ZONING
}
```

I have not tried the code but a similar code works for me in the attribute rules.